# Relative layout doesn't properly display as expected in Landscape view

Tags: android

Hi I'm making my first android program 'a calculator'. I was using the relative layout instead linear layout and I found some problems when it running it in the emulator.

1) the frame has not centered in the screen. 2) Once it is in the landscape mode, the numbers again goes to left side instead of centering it.

I tried many ways but still the problem remains same.

[image]

[image]

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:background="#fbf8c9"
                android:editable="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:onClick="buttonOnClick" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2"
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_above="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button"
                android:onClick="buttonOnClick" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="3"
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
                android:onClick="buttonOnClick" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="4"
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
                android:onClick="buttonOnClick" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="5"
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_above="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
                android:onClick="buttonOnClick" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="6"
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
                android:onClick="buttonOnClick" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="7"
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button4"
                android:onClick="buttonOnClick" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="8"
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button6"
                android:onClick="buttonOnClick" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="9"
                android:id="@+id/button9"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button8"
                android:onClick="buttonOnClick" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="0"
                android:id="@+id/button10"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button12"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button12"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button12"
                android:onClick="buttonOnClick" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="+"
                android:id="@+id/button11"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button12"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button12"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button12"
                android:onClick="buttonOnClick" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="="
                android:id="@+id/button12"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button9"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button9"
                android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
                android:background="#dcfa82" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="*"
                android:id="@+id/button13"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button3"
                android:onClick="buttonOnClick" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="/"
                android:id="@+id/button14"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button6"
                android:onClick="buttonOnClick" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="-"
                android:id="@+id/button15"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button9"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button9"
                android:onClick="buttonOnClick" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="AC"
                android:id="@+id/button16"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button10"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:onClick="buttonOnClick" />



            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:background="#fbf8c9"
                android:editable="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

please someone kindly help me in solving this issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest wrapping all the buttons in a View which itself can be centered in the RelativeLayout, such as a TableLayout. Here is a LinearLayout approach since you really only need the button-grid centered in a RelativeLayout. You can get all the buttons to fill the screen (like in the third photo) in a TableLayout using `android:stretchColumns="*"`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:background="#fbf8c9"/>
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fbf8c9"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"/>

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                 android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
        <TableRow>
            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:onClick="buttonOnClick"/>

            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:onClick="buttonOnClick"/>

            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="3"
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:onClick="buttonOnClick"/>

            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="*"
                    android:id="@+id/button13"
                    android:onClick="buttonOnClick"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="4"
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    android:onClick="buttonOnClick"/>

            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="5"
                    android:id="@+id/button5"
                    android:onClick="buttonOnClick"/>

            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="6"
                    android:id="@+id/button6"
                    android:onClick="buttonOnClick"/>

            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="/"
                    android:id="@+id/button14"
                    android:onClick="buttonOnClick"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="7"
                    android:id="@+id/button7"
                    android:onClick="buttonOnClick"/>

            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="8"
                    android:id="@+id/button8"
                    android:onClick="buttonOnClick"/>

            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="9"
                    android:id="@+id/button9"
                    android:onClick="buttonOnClick"/>
            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="-"
                    android:id="@+id/button15"
                    android:onClick="buttonOnClick"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="AC"
                    android:id="@+id/button16"
                    android:onClick="buttonOnClick"/>

            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="="
                    android:id="@+id/button12"
                    android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
                    android:background="#dcfa82"/>


            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:id="@+id/button10"
                    android:onClick="buttonOnClick"/>

            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="+"
                    android:id="@+id/button11"
                    android:onClick="buttonOnClick"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Portrait]
[image: Landscape - Center]

[image: Landscape - Stretch]

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#fbf8c9"
        android:editable="true"
        android:text="123243"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLefttOf="@+id/button2"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
            android:text="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
            android:text="3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
            android:text="4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
            android:text="5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
            android:text="6" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
            android:text="7" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button6"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
            android:text="8" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button8"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
            android:text="9" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button12"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button12"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button12"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
            android:text="0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button12"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button12"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button12"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
            android:text="+" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:background="#dcfa82"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
            android:text="=" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
            android:text="*" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button6"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
            android:text="/" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button9"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
            android:text="-" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button16"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button10"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
            android:text="AC" />
    </RelativeLayout>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:background="#fbf8c9"
            android:editable="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Portrait: 
[image: Portrait]

Landscape:
[image: Landscape]

Answer (score 1):

Below code should work, but I don't suggest using RelativeLayout which causes slow performance compared to other ViewGroups. Also you should reference existing calculator apps and [separate portrait and landscape into 2 different layouts](http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html#create-layouts).

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#fbf8c9"
        android:editable="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#fbf8c9"
        android:editable="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLefttOf="@+id/button2"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
            android:text="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
            android:text="3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
            android:text="4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
            android:text="5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
            android:text="6" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
            android:text="7" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button6"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
            android:text="8" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button8"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
            android:text="9" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button12"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button12"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button12"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
            android:text="0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button12"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button12"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button12"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
            android:text="+" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:background="#dcfa82"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
            android:text="=" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
            android:text="*" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button6"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
            android:text="/" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button9"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
            android:text="-" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button16"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button10"
            android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
            android:text="AC" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```